# Marriage of orthogonal array with a conditional requirement in R

Tags: r, arrays, orthogonal

I am a novice so my code will not be elegant!

I'm trying to determine an optimized 'recipe' of 6 ingredients with 5 levels of use.
Ingredients - (A, B, C, D, E, F)
Levels - (0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%)

A full factorial (see code using fac.design from DoE.base) returns 15,625 possibilities with no repeats. After subsetting the result to eliminate all recipes that sums > 100%, I am left with 126 sample recipes.

My question is - Is it possible to apply the conditional require (the factors can only sum to 100%) to an orthogonal array to further reduce the necessary samples without giving up significant statistical power?

Here's my code -

```
library(DoE.base)
library(openxlsx)


antibodies <- 6   ### how many antibodies?
percent <- 5      ### how many levels or percentages of contribution to the recipe?

FF <- fac.design(nfactors = antibodies, nlevels = percent)  ## this creates a full factorial

  FF$new <- c(0)  ## this adds a new column to FF and fills it with zeros
  colnames(FF) <- c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "Total")  ## this renames the columns
  
  FF$A <- as.numeric(FF$A)   ## changes char to numeric
  FF$B <- as.numeric(FF$B)
  FF$C <- as.numeric(FF$C)
  FF$D <- as.numeric(FF$D)
  FF$E <- as.numeric(FF$E)
  FF$F <- as.numeric(FF$F)
  FF$Total <- as.numeric(FF$Total)

  FF[FF == 1] <- 0.00 ## update if percentages change
  FF[FF == 2] <- 0.25  ## use this to replace the char "2" with the numeric 0.25
  FF[FF == 3] <- 0.50
  FF[FF == 4] <- 0.75
  FF[FF == 5] <- 1.00
  
  attach(FF)
  
  i <- 1   ### this replaces the zeroes with the summation of each antibodies' contribution
  for (i in 1:15625) {
    FF$Total <- c(A+B+C+D+E+F)
    i <- (i+1)
  }
  
  ff1 <- subset(FF, select = A:Total, subset = (Total == 1))  ##  this subsets only the recipes that total 100%

  
  write.xlsx(ff1, file = 'Padakonn Full Factorial Antibody Sampling Plan.xlsx')
```

Comment: Also I should point out that the code yields the full factorial solution. I'm looking to see if there is a way to add the recipe requirement (factors can only sum to 100%) to the oa.design function in DoE.base or is there an alternative method to analyze the recipes with decreased samples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem describes a [mixture design](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section5/pri54.htm) that involves sampling on a simplex. A couple packages described below may be of interest.

From the `mixexp` package, the `SLD` function will create a simplex lattice design:

```
mixexp::SLD(6, 4)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'DoE.base':
#>   method           from       
#>   factorize.factor conf.design
#>       x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6
#> 1   1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 2   0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 3   0.50 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 4   0.25 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 5   0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 6   0.75 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 7   0.50 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 8   0.25 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 9   0.00 0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 10  0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 11  0.25 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 12  0.00 0.50 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 13  0.25 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 14  0.00 0.25 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 15  0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#> 16  0.75 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 17  0.50 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 18  0.25 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 19  0.00 0.75 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 20  0.50 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 21  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 22  0.00 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 23  0.25 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 24  0.00 0.25 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 25  0.00 0.00 0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00
#> 26  0.50 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00
#> 27  0.25 0.25 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00
#> 28  0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00
#> 29  0.25 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.00
#> 30  0.00 0.25 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.00
#> 31  0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50 0.00 0.00
#> 32  0.25 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00
#> 33  0.00 0.25 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00
#> 34  0.00 0.00 0.25 0.75 0.00 0.00
#> 35  0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00
#> 36  0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 37  0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 38  0.25 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 39  0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 40  0.50 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 41  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 42  0.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 43  0.25 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 44  0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 45  0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.25 0.00
#> 46  0.50 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00
#> 47  0.25 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00
#> 48  0.00 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00
#> 49  0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00
#> 50  0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00
#> 51  0.00 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.00
#> 52  0.25 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.00
#> 53  0.00 0.25 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.00
#> 54  0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.25 0.00
#> 55  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.25 0.00
#> 56  0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00
#> 57  0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00
#> 58  0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00
#> 59  0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.50 0.00
#> 60  0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.50 0.00
#> 61  0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00
#> 62  0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00
#> 63  0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00
#> 64  0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.50 0.00
#> 65  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50 0.00
#> 66  0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00
#> 67  0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00
#> 68  0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.75 0.00
#> 69  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.75 0.00
#> 70  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
#> 71  0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 72  0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 73  0.25 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 74  0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 75  0.50 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 76  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 77  0.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 78  0.25 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 79  0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 80  0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.25
#> 81  0.50 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25
#> 82  0.25 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25
#> 83  0.00 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25
#> 84  0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.25
#> 85  0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.25
#> 86  0.00 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.25
#> 87  0.25 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.25
#> 88  0.00 0.25 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.25
#> 89  0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.00 0.25
#> 90  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.25
#> 91  0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25
#> 92  0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25
#> 93  0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25
#> 94  0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25
#> 95  0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25
#> 96  0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.25
#> 97  0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25
#> 98  0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25
#> 99  0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
#> 100 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.25 0.25
#> 101 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.25
#> 102 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.25
#> 103 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.50 0.25
#> 104 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.25
#> 105 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.25
#> 106 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50
#> 107 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50
#> 108 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50
#> 109 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.50
#> 110 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.50
#> 111 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.50
#> 112 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.50
#> 113 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.50
#> 114 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.50
#> 115 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50
#> 116 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50
#> 117 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50
#> 118 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.50
#> 119 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.50
#> 120 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50
#> 121 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.75
#> 122 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.75
#> 123 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.75
#> 124 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.75
#> 125 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.75
#> 126 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00
```

If the mixture proportions can be varied continuously independent of ingredient, a normalized maximum projection design may give better coverage. Using the `MaxProLHD` from the `MaxPro` package (which has the advantage of being able to specify the number of recipes):

```
dm <- MaxPro::MaxProLHD(126, 6)$Design
dm <- dm/rowSums(dm)
dm
#>               [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
#>   [1,] 0.001373626 0.256868132 0.270604396 0.166208791 0.267857143 0.037087912
#>   [2,] 0.004335260 0.143063584 0.354046243 0.270231214 0.102601156 0.125722543
#>   [3,] 0.007440476 0.337797619 0.233630952 0.111607143 0.123511905 0.186011905
#>   [4,] 0.012635379 0.027075812 0.074007220 0.229241877 0.445848375 0.211191336
#>   [5,] 0.012430939 0.180939227 0.319060773 0.029005525 0.321823204 0.136740331
#>   [6,] 0.020992366 0.307251908 0.032442748 0.211832061 0.257633588 0.169847328
#>   [7,] 0.019345238 0.212797619 0.209821429 0.043154762 0.147321429 0.367559524
#>   [8,] 0.023148148 0.016975309 0.371913580 0.066358025 0.202160494 0.319444444
#>   [9,] 0.023351648 0.072802198 0.226648352 0.292582418 0.229395604 0.155219780
#>  [10,] 0.030448718 0.293269231 0.161858974 0.280448718 0.017628205 0.216346154
#>  [11,] 0.071917808 0.414383562 0.167808219 0.229452055 0.065068493 0.051369863
#>  [12,] 0.032951289 0.348137536 0.184813754 0.021489971 0.181948424 0.230659026
#>  [13,] 0.044642857 0.180357143 0.269642857 0.080357143 0.333928571 0.091071429
#>  [14,] 0.031690141 0.261737089 0.092723005 0.080985915 0.285211268 0.247652582
#>  [15,] 0.055769231 0.325000000 0.128846154 0.305769231 0.178846154 0.005769231
#>  [16,] 0.044034091 0.055397727 0.305397727 0.183238636 0.146306818 0.265625000
#>  [17,] 0.068750000 0.172916667 0.360416667 0.168750000 0.060416667 0.168750000
#>  [18,] 0.045454545 0.180519481 0.325974026 0.175324675 0.198701299 0.074025974
#>  [19,] 0.040838852 0.259381898 0.230684327 0.113686534 0.237306843 0.118101545
#>  [20,] 0.060000000 0.124615385 0.050769231 0.355384615 0.346153846 0.063076923
#>  [21,] 0.079150579 0.129343629 0.164092664 0.202702703 0.086872587 0.337837838
#>  [22,] 0.054430380 0.163291139 0.236708861 0.226582278 0.163291139 0.155696203
#>  [23,] 0.065217391 0.004347826 0.108695652 0.242028986 0.297101449 0.282608696
#>  [24,] 0.125668449 0.056149733 0.072192513 0.082887701 0.227272727 0.435828877
#>  [25,] 0.062500000 0.246173469 0.195153061 0.286989796 0.184948980 0.024234694
#>  [26,] 0.070247934 0.128099174 0.304407713 0.089531680 0.084022039 0.323691460
#>  [27,] 0.072207084 0.039509537 0.317438692 0.276566757 0.246594005 0.047683924
#>  [28,] 0.115062762 0.278242678 0.194560669 0.102510460 0.156903766 0.152719665
#>  [29,] 0.102517986 0.016187050 0.246402878 0.264388489 0.199640288 0.170863309
#>  [30,] 0.134703196 0.171232877 0.422374429 0.020547945 0.203196347 0.047945205
#>  [31,] 0.098070740 0.245980707 0.020900322 0.004823151 0.381028939 0.249196141
#>  [32,] 0.073085847 0.203016241 0.135730858 0.154292343 0.200696056 0.233178654
#>  [33,] 0.092329545 0.058238636 0.044034091 0.285511364 0.197443182 0.322443182
#>  [34,] 0.065429688 0.209960938 0.166992188 0.190429688 0.239257812 0.127929688
#>  [35,] 0.151982379 0.143171806 0.015418502 0.169603524 0.376651982 0.143171806
#>  [36,] 0.098611111 0.320833333 0.159722222 0.298611111 0.029166667 0.093055556
#>  [37,] 0.100274725 0.168956044 0.061813187 0.207417582 0.265109890 0.196428571
#>  [38,] 0.116459627 0.259316770 0.277950311 0.051242236 0.020186335 0.274844720
#>  [39,] 0.093446602 0.066747573 0.299757282 0.270631068 0.003640777 0.265776699
#>  [40,] 0.080942623 0.201844262 0.230532787 0.212090164 0.111680328 0.162909836
#>  [41,] 0.139175258 0.156357388 0.104810997 0.338487973 0.056701031 0.204467354
#>  [42,] 0.126911315 0.380733945 0.212538226 0.166666667 0.077981651 0.035168196
#>  [43,] 0.096810934 0.051252847 0.176537585 0.130979499 0.274487472 0.269931663
#>  [44,] 0.145484950 0.128762542 0.185618729 0.155518395 0.202341137 0.182274247
#>  [45,] 0.153448276 0.377586207 0.043103448 0.101724138 0.260344828 0.063793103
#>  [46,] 0.099780702 0.069078947 0.224780702 0.202850877 0.218201754 0.185307018
#>  [47,] 0.192148760 0.035123967 0.402892562 0.283057851 0.072314050 0.014462810
#>  [48,] 0.179245283 0.107547170 0.100000000 0.326415094 0.198113208 0.088679245
#>  [49,] 0.094357977 0.222762646 0.193579767 0.144941634 0.119649805 0.224708171
#>  [50,] 0.097633136 0.113412229 0.141025641 0.231755424 0.214003945 0.202169625
#>  [51,] 0.198039216 0.143137255 0.076470588 0.092156863 0.017647059 0.472549020
#>  [52,] 0.121749409 0.128841608 0.277777778 0.100472813 0.192671395 0.178486998
#>  [53,] 0.193726937 0.348708487 0.005535055 0.267527675 0.046125461 0.138376384
#>  [54,] 0.129539952 0.175544794 0.083535109 0.267554479 0.216707022 0.127118644
#>  [55,] 0.206439394 0.024621212 0.248106061 0.168560606 0.001893939 0.350378788
#>  [56,] 0.135365854 0.164634146 0.132926829 0.230487805 0.067073171 0.269512195
#>  [57,] 0.102727273 0.228181818 0.146363636 0.220909091 0.144545455 0.157272727
#>  [58,] 0.121822034 0.166313559 0.204449153 0.166313559 0.265889831 0.075211864
#>  [59,] 0.139952153 0.233253589 0.147129187 0.068181818 0.266746411 0.144736842
#>  [60,] 0.129912664 0.201965066 0.258733624 0.271834061 0.088427948 0.049126638
#>  [61,] 0.241035857 0.065737052 0.316733068 0.073705179 0.097609562 0.205179283
#>  [62,] 0.150366748 0.289731051 0.062347188 0.033007335 0.231051345 0.233496333
#>  [63,] 0.164473684 0.125000000 0.027631579 0.203947368 0.148684211 0.330263158
#>  [64,] 0.146651270 0.259815242 0.121247113 0.142032333 0.162817552 0.167436490
#>  [65,] 0.164961637 0.257033248 0.231457801 0.116368286 0.223785166 0.006393862
#>  [66,] 0.301843318 0.366359447 0.163594470 0.011520737 0.089861751 0.066820276
#>  [67,] 0.173177083 0.066406250 0.105468750 0.319010417 0.162760417 0.173177083
#>  [68,] 0.140918580 0.213987474 0.011482255 0.191022965 0.220250522 0.222338205
#>  [69,] 0.146055437 0.256929638 0.242004264 0.105543710 0.033049041 0.216417910
#>  [70,] 0.176395939 0.191624365 0.112944162 0.092639594 0.196700508 0.229695431
#>  [71,] 0.205539359 0.001457726 0.217201166 0.319241983 0.039358601 0.217201166
#>  [72,] 0.189655172 0.253315650 0.269230769 0.025198939 0.078249337 0.184350133
#>  [73,] 0.199175824 0.141483516 0.089285714 0.133241758 0.328296703 0.108516484
#>  [74,] 0.228260870 0.054347826 0.141304348 0.218944099 0.023291925 0.333850932
#>  [75,] 0.323913043 0.093478261 0.080434783 0.076086957 0.397826087 0.028260870
#>  [76,] 0.155030801 0.089322382 0.124229979 0.181724846 0.255646817 0.194045175
#>  [77,] 0.168874172 0.239514349 0.065121413 0.186534216 0.069536424 0.270419426
#>  [78,] 0.170329670 0.181318681 0.124175824 0.264835165 0.223076923 0.036263736
#>  [79,] 0.164225941 0.072175732 0.174686192 0.250000000 0.095188285 0.243723849
#>  [80,] 0.217808219 0.080821918 0.300000000 0.075342466 0.201369863 0.124657534
#>  [81,] 0.201754386 0.224310777 0.058897243 0.239348371 0.196741855 0.078947368
#>  [82,] 0.192671395 0.239952719 0.086288416 0.275413712 0.008274232 0.197399527
#>  [83,] 0.199275362 0.030193237 0.221014493 0.027777778 0.252415459 0.269323671
#>  [84,] 0.147266314 0.184303351 0.210758377 0.099647266 0.200176367 0.157848325
#>  [85,] 0.322519084 0.051526718 0.043893130 0.345419847 0.078244275 0.158396947
#>  [86,] 0.347560976 0.010162602 0.217479675 0.022357724 0.290650407 0.111788618
#>  [87,] 0.283606557 0.080327869 0.309836066 0.155737705 0.106557377 0.063934426
#>  [88,] 0.277777778 0.188888889 0.087301587 0.061904762 0.182539683 0.201587302
#>  [89,] 0.149241147 0.152613828 0.149241147 0.177908938 0.161045531 0.209949410
#>  [90,] 0.218826406 0.128361858 0.165036675 0.201711491 0.094132029 0.191931540
#>  [91,] 0.249311295 0.337465565 0.114325069 0.086776860 0.078512397 0.133608815
#>  [92,] 0.253462604 0.148199446 0.278393352 0.001385042 0.303324100 0.015235457
#>  [93,] 0.218676123 0.204491726 0.270685579 0.190307329 0.005910165 0.109929078
#>  [94,] 0.225845411 0.266908213 0.114734300 0.240338164 0.121980676 0.030193237
#>  [95,] 0.215753425 0.097031963 0.236301370 0.247716895 0.135844749 0.067351598
#>  [96,] 0.212694878 0.141425390 0.032293987 0.096881960 0.246102450 0.270601336
#>  [97,] 0.288922156 0.046407186 0.007485030 0.178143713 0.223053892 0.255988024
#>  [98,] 0.218120805 0.166666667 0.148769575 0.139821029 0.231543624 0.095078300
#>  [99,] 0.324013158 0.100328947 0.103618421 0.027960526 0.120065789 0.324013158
#> [100,] 0.165008292 0.176616915 0.085406302 0.188225539 0.194859038 0.189883914
#> [101,] 0.242753623 0.298309179 0.018115942 0.167874396 0.213768116 0.059178744
#> [102,] 0.238823529 0.022352941 0.067058824 0.241176471 0.250588235 0.180000000
#> [103,] 0.208333333 0.157520325 0.129065041 0.255081301 0.037601626 0.212398374
#> [104,] 0.229490022 0.258314856 0.047671840 0.118625277 0.105321508 0.240576497
#> [105,] 0.221868365 0.132696391 0.173036093 0.181528662 0.245222930 0.045647558
#> [106,] 0.309384164 0.142228739 0.001466276 0.089442815 0.294721408 0.162756598
#> [107,] 0.308695652 0.305797101 0.210144928 0.059420290 0.114492754 0.001449275
#> [108,] 0.260922330 0.166262136 0.023058252 0.277912621 0.105582524 0.166262136
#> [109,] 0.200925926 0.130555556 0.195370370 0.108333333 0.156481481 0.208333333
#> [110,] 0.305865922 0.009776536 0.138268156 0.115921788 0.096368715 0.333798883
#> [111,] 0.255196305 0.135103926 0.287528868 0.061200924 0.049653580 0.211316397
#> [112,] 0.208801498 0.105805243 0.208801498 0.231273408 0.173220974 0.072097378
#> [113,] 0.315126050 0.032212885 0.175070028 0.228291317 0.225490196 0.023809524
#> [114,] 0.293281654 0.060723514 0.189922481 0.091731266 0.151162791 0.213178295
#> [115,] 0.306149733 0.105614973 0.012032086 0.279411765 0.030748663 0.266042781
#> [116,] 0.319944598 0.236842105 0.164819945 0.034626039 0.148199446 0.095567867
#> [117,] 0.269675926 0.230324074 0.195601852 0.151620370 0.019675926 0.133101852
#> [118,] 0.295969773 0.112090680 0.109571788 0.016372796 0.288413098 0.177581864
#> [119,] 0.207894737 0.209649123 0.186842105 0.207894737 0.058771930 0.128947368
#> [120,] 0.351470588 0.163235294 0.113235294 0.225000000 0.069117647 0.077941176
#> [121,] 0.250000000 0.073651452 0.252074689 0.148340249 0.142116183 0.133817427
#> [122,] 0.312339332 0.227506427 0.278920308 0.101542416 0.068123393 0.011568123
#> [123,] 0.226432532 0.150646950 0.176524954 0.178373383 0.089648799 0.178373383
#> [124,] 0.333783784 0.050000000 0.131081081 0.136486486 0.266216216 0.082432432
#> [125,] 0.325916230 0.270942408 0.045811518 0.009162304 0.215968586 0.132198953
#> [126,] 0.318527919 0.186548223 0.222081218 0.064720812 0.168781726 0.039340102
```

Notice that the maximum projection design is less aggressive at sampling the edges and corners of the simplex.

Lastly, [this paper](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/86061237/j.foodqual.2017.01.00420220517-1-1dhrcgb-with-cover-page-v2.pdf?Expires=1660569348&Signature=LwUfgI4LV-2ca-TaQB578TZhAvE8haA8Ijp1yXmKsGmlDYx7wEu6Yx1gB6UK5ejvSMBv20CrXfnIPFWeL46%7E3V2dhFRe3ceUDBgu2YeXkOSt0ets4LYVnp424f9Mv%7EnOytIVzcUU9Nqk-hkYXsv4twGQmQh5RBS9yrUZ%7EKCqAK9p0Lw-EFMLEzh67mATMuAr8e3vhsIQZLNw7i6lUfp--lTAVdJC%7ESmu8F37u9Q81OSq26Ira2q919vB0gt%7EaAq87KIY0UR5Ss8uSRExrKsCu7Imq0pFqjfkCGcLrUnOZT7nnVBZlaOHAKzXE72Y5Ssa9fWdIOoruZgyJI8YMrXkMg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) describes an approach using a normalized fractional factorial design.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Maybe I didn't state the question succinctly - is there a way to get the sample efficiency using an orthogonal array with a requirement for the conditional statement?

Comment: To look at this problem another way, using oa.design (from DoE.base) for a 6 factor, 5 level returns 25 sample 'recipes'. The results however are not filtered through the requirement that the factors can only sum to 100% (all ingredients in the 'recipe' can only total to 100%). Is there a method to require a fractional factorial/orthogonal array to also be bound by the "total == 100%" requirement?